# Problema con Instalacion de temas envato en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Buen dia comunidad, hace poco entre a un pagina llamada envato market, Pude ver que ofrecen contenido gratuito todos los meses y luego de descargar una plantilla para wordpress, mi pagina no permite su instalacion. dice No se ha podido descomprimir el paquete. El tema no tiene la hoja de estilos style.css.

Alguien sabe donde la encuentro?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que este es un problema común en los temas de Envato Market, primero descargue todos los archivos de su cuenta de Envato, luego de descargarlos descomprímalo, busque el archivo  .zip que contiene su tema y descomprímalo también, una vez se haya descomprimido verifique que la hoja de estilos style.css se encuentre entre los archivos.

[image]

Si se encuentra entre los archivos vuelva a comprimir el tema (Solo el tema, si se descargo todos los archivos tendrá un archivo .zip con mas archivos .zip dentro busque el .zip que contiene su tema), súbalo de nuevo y verifique si sigue dando el error, si aun así no funciona prueba a descomprimir la carpeta del tema y subirla manualmente a la carpeta de su instalación de WordPress, /wp-content/themes/

[image]

Si la hoja de estilos, style.css no se encuentra en su tema, comuníquese con el autor y reporte el problema.

Para mas información visite la [pagina de soporte de Envato Market](https://help.market.envato.com/hc/en-us/articles/202821510-Theme-is-missing-the-style-css-stylesheet-error)

Comment: Logre encontrar un zip dentro del que ofrecen en la pagina para descargar y al momento de aplicar el tema me tumbó la pagina.